# Bind: file does not end with newline

Tags: bind, dns

Named не стартует.

Проверяю `named.conf` на ошибки -- ответ OK, но при проверке зоны пишет:

```
TTL set to prior TTL (86400)
file does not end with newline
TTL set to prior TTL (86400)
zone 192.168.0/IN: loaded serial 2012122805
OK
```

Не могу понять значения второй строчки. Видел множество конфигов, делал все по статьям, книгам и т.д., но все равно ошибка.

Что означает вторая строка и как с этим бороться?

Comment: Ответ прост - в любые конфиги на Linux системах добавляйте новую строку. Для зон есть свои конфиги, в них и ковыряйтесь.

Answer (score 1):

в приведённой информации нет никаких сообщений об ошибках.

а почему именно не запускается программа *bind*, можно узнать из содержимого логов.

куда сохраняются логи, возможно, подскажет содержимое упомянутого конфигурационного файла (`named.conf`).

Answer (score -1):

Файл `*.conf` должен заканчиваться. Отредактируй чтобы курсор стоял в конце файла  с чистой строки.